# File permissions for Django: Gunicorn, Nginx, and Static Files

Tags: linux, django, nginx

I have a standard ubuntu 14.04 machine. I use it daily under the user `mh00h`. I'm interested in using this machine as a production server. How do I manage file permissions for Django and Nginx?

Nginx is currently configured to run under the `www-data:www-data`. This minimizes risk of the rest of a machine being compromised. Django/gunicorn likewise should run under a user other than `mh00h`. But under what user should gunicorn actually be run under? `nobody`, correct?

Next: I am storing all of my web development files under `/home/mh00h/development`. Owned by `mh00h`. `/home/mh00h/development/project1 (plus all dir/files but /media and /static)`? Owned by `mh00h`. I follow django two-scoops best practices to create a project directory with static files inside of it. Of course, Nginx is unable to access `/home/mh00h/development/project1/project1/static` now because all of those parent directories are owned by `mh00h`, not `www-data` (`./static` is owned by `www-data`).

To complicate the matter, virtualenvwrapper creates my virtual environments under `/home/mh00h/.virtualenvs/`.

I am hesitant to fraction away from two scoop's best practices and store `/static` separately in `/var/www`, because I want all of these directories to stay nicely packaged together for easy transport off to some other server later. Plus, it makes me messy if I compare myself against how two-scoops did it.

1. Where should my static files be stored?
2. Where should django specific files be stored?
3. What users/groups should be able to access which of 1 and 2?
4. Where should virtualenvwrapper environments be stored?
5. What permissions should these locations have?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All files and directories in our production environment are owned by `root:root` with 755/644 file permissions, unless otherwise required. Some private files (think private keys etc.) are only readable by the user/process that needs them, while still being writable only by `root`.

As for the project structure: all our projects have a dedicated directory under `/srv/www/vhosts.d/`. Virtual environments are stored under `/srv/www/virtualenvs`. It is perfectly possible to store them in your home folder, but I feel this central approach is more in line with the idea of a production server. With the right settings, all virtual envs are also accessible by all users.

Our main project directory contains several scripts (manage.py and several deployment/update scripts) and is further split out into subdirectores: i.e. `web` contains public files, `src` contains the source code, and `frontend` contains the template folder and sass folder. The whole project directory is contained in a git repository, but deployment-specific files (user uploaded files, search indexes, encryption keys) are all in `.git-ignore`.

Our nginx process runs as `www-data`. In general each Django project has its own user, and the gunicorn process runs as this user.